# Keeping M/D date format when a cell is included in a string

Tags: string, date, google-sheets

I have dates in Col A.
Col B ="I23-"&A2&"-"

A2 is 8/3 but
B2 output is I23-45141-

I tried using ="I23-"&TO_DATE(A2)&"-" and I still get the same output no matter what.
How do I keep the date in it's original format when used in a string to get Col B value?

Comment: So far my solution is to create another Col that uses "=if(isblank(A2)=FALSE,Left(A2,3),)" to get it out of it's original date format and then that seems to work

Comment: `45141` is nothing but value of date `8/3/2023`. So, you have to use some date conversion function like `TEXT()`. Try `="I23-"& TEXT(A2,"m/d")&"-"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use TEXT choosing the format you need, as Harun suggested, or you can try with TO_TEXT, which should present the information in the cell as it was originally presented:

```
="I23-"&TO_TEXT(A2)&"-"
```

Comment: Thanks  :) .  I figured TO_DATE would work better than TO_TEXT